# Police officer working undercover as an inmate

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a term for a police officer or someone else working for a country's security forces who masquerades as an inmate and is put into a cell with a suspect in order to extract information?

I'm not sure that informant works here..

Comment: Also a plant. . .

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think stool pigeon is something different than questioner is describing. A stool pigeon would be used for  a **real** inmate who grasses or informs, as opposed to a planted undercover officer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think most people would use the informal and colloquial word [**mole**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mole):

> **4** : a spy (such as a double agent) who establishes a cover long before beginning espionage
>   *broadly* : one within an organization who passes on information

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(espionage)) says more about its applicability to police officers specifically:

> In police work, a mole is an undercover law-enforcement agent who joins an organization in order to collect incriminating evidence about its operations and so bring its members to justice.

Comment: Seems to me that would mean that a mole is planted in order to catch police officers... but I'm looking for the guy used against ordinary criminal suspects, terror operatives, etc.

Comment: @Ilanysong In police work, a mole is a police officer who is planted to catch somebody in some organization. It *could* be somebody from internal affairs (a police officer trying to catch other police officers), but that would be unusual. In almost every case, a mole is planted to catch so-called regular criminals.

Comment: I see. I'm quite ignorant on police work, so I'll take your word for it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I would probably use ***infiltrator*** as a general term, though more specifically, in this situation an ***undercover police officer***.

As the below quotation from the OED will illustrate, the verb ***infiltrate*** is used figuratively, in a political sense, normally to describe a process of political subversion. However armies and law enforcement authorities can and have ***infiltrated*** the hierarchies of insurgent and subversive movements in order to gain information.

It has been a method, used by Britain in colonial situations against such as the *Mau Mau* in Kenya, and the Communists in Malaya. It was also a process which played a big part in the destabilisation of the IRA in Northern Ireland.

Police forces ***infiltrate*** criminal gangs, and hence the placing of an ***undercover officer*** in a cell would seem to me to amount to much the same thing - to gain information on a wider criminal organisation, or group of accomplices.

> **Infiltrate-*verb*** 4. Military. transitive and intransitive. To penetrate (enemy lines) by the gradual or surreptitious movement of small numbers of troops;
>   to move (one's own troops) surreptitiously into the enemy's lines.
>   Also **figurative, esp. for the purpose of political subversion**.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - infiltrate would definitely be the right verb to use in this context. Undercover police officer works fine, too, I prefer mole because it's "short and sweet :).